# include quantifier in character class

Tags: php, regex, expression

How am I able to add a quantifier inside a character class? This is my current regular expression and what I want to achieve (besides what it is doing right now) is that whitespaces and dots (with an oncurrence of more than 2) will be matched and finally be removed using the preg_replace function

Current regular expression:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s.\'\(\)\-\_]
```

Desired solution (notice the quantifier {1}):

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s{1}.{1}\'\(\)\-\_]
```

Input (that has to be filtered):

```
Hi, this is a text.......that has    to be filtered!@#!
```

Output (After the regular expression):

```
Hi this is a textthat hasto be filtered
```

Comment: This is not possible, you might be searching for something like `[^A-Za-z0-9\s.'()_-]|[\s.]{2,}`

Comment: @SebastianProske So I would have to run 3 different regular expression in order to receive my desired solution? Since the regular expression you've sent me has an alternative included*

Comment: show the input string and the expected output(result)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear on what you actually wnat to achieve, but seems like a x-y-problem to me.

Comment: You are attempting to use the quantifier {1} but your example says that you want to remove "more than one"? Or is it "more than 2"?

Comment: @AndyG More than 2. But the example I wrote, matches everything NOT listed in the character set. So.. what i'm trying to achieve is that ONE white-space / dot is allowed, but having multiple oncurrences not.

Comment: I would take two stages. Removing the more than two, something like `(\.{2,}|\s{2,})`, then remove the non-alpha characters. But more than two uses `{3,}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility for a quantifier inside a character class. However you could use alternation and normal quantifiers, like

```
$str = "Hi, this is a text.......that has    to be filtered!@#!";
$pattern = "/[^A-Za-z0-9\\s.'()_-]|\\.{3,}|\\s{3,}/";
$subst = "";
print(preg_replace($pattern, $subst, $str));
```

Outputs: `Hi this is a textthat hasto be filtered`

You could also shorten the character class to `[^\\w\\s.'()-]`

In the regex `[^A-Za-z0-9\\s.'()_-]` matches any character that is not alphanumeric or whitespace or dot or round bracket or apostrophe or underscore or minus. `\\.{3,}` matches any dot with a occurance of 3 or more (more than 2). `\\s{3,}` matches any whitespace with a occurance of 3 or more (more than 2) - note that this will match e.g. blank tab blank, as these are all whitespace characters.

With the empty string substitution, everything matched will be replaced by an empty string (thus removed).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your idea. I managed fixing it using the following regular expression \.{2,}|\s{2,}|[^A-Za-z0-9 .\'\(\)\-\_] - I'm a real noob at regular expressions, so could you may explain me the what yours does?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$str = "Hi, this is a text.......that has    to be filtered!@#!";

$replaced = preg_replace_callback(
        ["/(\s{3,}|\.{3,})/" , "/[^A-Za-z0-9\s.'()_-]/" ],
        function($m) { return ""; },
        $str);

print_r($replaced);
```

The output:

```
Hi this is a textthat hasto be filtered
```